# Determinant of an elementary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I read a very slick proof of determinant properties, in this case of the fact $\det A = \det A^T$, which says in one place

> It suffices to notice that for any elementary matrix $M$ we have $\det M = \det M^T$

But it's not obvious to me. How can we show it?

Note: we're using the Laplace expansion for rows as the definition. It was noted that for elementary matrix $M$ we have $\det M = 1$ if $M$ adds a multiplied row, $\det M = -1$ if $M$ swaps two rows and $\det M = c$ if $M$ multiplies one row by $c$.

Comment: Try writing each elementary operation as a matrix, then take its determinant and transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 3 cases:

1) $M$ multiplies a row by $c$

Then $M$ looks like
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & & \\
  & 1 \\
  &  &  \ddots \\
  &  &  & 1 \\
  &  &  &  & c \\
  &  &  &  & & 1 \\
  &  &  &  &&&\ddots \\
  &  &  &  &&&& 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
So trivally $M^T = M$, hence the equality of deteminants

2) $M$ adds another row. Then the $M$ looks like
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & & \\
  & 1 & \ldots & a \\
  &  &  \ddots & \vdots \\
  &  &  & 1 \\
  &  &  &  &\ddots \\
  &  &  &  && 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
By doing the Laplace expansion at the column containing $a$, we get
$$detM = (-1)^{i+j} a \det I + (-1)^{j+j} \det I$$.
This is symmetrical wrt to $i,j$, so in this case $\det M = \det M^T$ too

3) $M$ swaps two rows. Then $M$ looks like
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & & \\
  & \ddots \\
  &  &  1 \\
  &  &  & 0 & & &  & 1 \\
  &  &  &  & 1 \\
  &  &  && & \ddots \\
  &  &  & & & & 1 \\
  &  &  & 1 & & & & 0 \\
  &  &  & & & & & & 1 \\
  &  &  & & & & & & & \ddots \\
  &  &  & & & &&& &&1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
This matrix is symmetrical, so $M = M^T$, hence the equality of determinants.

Comment: Your second case is wrong, In (2) it's not necessarily the case that $\tilde M_{ij}=I$.

Comment: Say $M=I_n$, then $\tilde M_{ij}=I_{n-1}$ iff $i=j$. And albeit you're wrong at this part your result is correct because the $\det(\tilde{I_{ij}})=0$ when $i\not=j$ so $(-1)^{i+j} a \det(\tilde{I_{ij}})$ is zero.